# Placing C++ class in another file: compilation error

Tags: c++, class

I am learning about C++ classes and I realized that if I tried to move my class declaration and definition of `class Date` from `main.cpp` to another c++ file, say `test.cpp`  and compiled the two files I got an error saying Date was not declared. Why is that?

Comment: Please include more information or post code. For compilation errors like this it's more important that the class is defined (usually from another .h file and through an #include directive.)

Comment: @ChrisA.: Do you mean *declared*?

Comment: You might want to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923961/source-file-and-header-in-c/6924146#6924146)

Comment: @bitmask: More likely Chris is talking about a class _definition_. A class _declaration_ is used rarely. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration/1410632#1410632) for the difference.

Comment: @sbi: `me += knowledge` ... I've been using the wrong words for ages. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, "declared" would have been sufficient.  "Class definition" also works.

Comment: @ChrisA.: There is a big difference between a class _declaration_ and a class _definition_. (For example, you cannot access any members of a class that's only been _declared_.) Please see the link I provided.

Comment: @sbi, I understand that difference and was saying you're correct.  I misspoke in my original statement and was suggesting two possible corrections that make the statement correct.

Comment: @ChrisA: Ah, sorry for misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why you have header files. You need a header file `test.h` that contains only the *class definition* (that is mostly function declarations) and `test.cpp` that contains the actual *function definitions* (the code).

In `main.cpp` you'll have to `#include "test.h"`.

Comment: You probably need the class *definition* (but not any *function definitions*) in the header file, otherwise you'll have to deal with it as an incomplete type.

Comment: Note that the rules are completely different for template types, and that static variables should be instantiated in the .cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would have to declare your class in test.h and include it in main.cpp so that the compiler knows where to look for it and you can then define your class in test.cpp