# C++ compiling different .cpp files including them in the header file

Tags: c++

As i said in the title i want to know if is an error to include .cpp files in their respectively .h

I'm compiling using cygwin on windows. The g++ compiler was installed in cygwin using `apt-cyg install g++`.
Then i added the cygwin path to env and now the g++ command is reachable from a windows cmd.

Here's a basic example to reproduce the problem.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tezt.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    tezt();
    return 0;
}
```

**tezt.h**

```
#ifndef TEZT_H
#define TEZT_H

void tezt();

#endif
```

**tezt.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tezt.h"

void tezt() 
{
    std::cout<<"tezt"<<std::endl;
}
```

If i compile using simply `g++ main.cpp` i get errors.
So in order to compile correctly i should type `g++ main.cpp tezt.cpp` or define libraries.
It can be a trivial task when managing with multiple .cpp files stored in different folders.

---

So i'm proposing this approach:
if i modify the content of tezt.h, like follow, compilation is successfully! It can be a good "workaround" or it's not recommended? It's a colossal stupidity?

```
#ifndef TEZT_H
#define TEZT_H
#include "tezt.cpp"

void tezt();

#endif
```

---

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: not really colossal and I wouldnt call it stupidity, but yeah its the latter. Dont include source files. Looking for a dupe....

Comment: It wont work if you include the same `.h` file in more than one `.cpp` file. So, no. Don't do that. Use a build system instead. [Meson](https://mesonbuild.com/) is becoming very popular and is quite easy to learn too. I highly recommend spending some time with it.

Comment: How to manage larger multi-sourcefile projects depends on your platform and your own preferences. If you like integrated environments then an IDE is a good choice. If you want command-line only then on Linux systems the `make` program and `Makefile` is something you need to learn. There are many other build-systems available.

Comment: I not really sure what you want, but if you want the implementation in a single file, then problably you want to put everything in the header.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923961/source-file-and-header-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it is a bad idea to have an implementation in the header file.
if you include `tezt.h` file in different files in the same project it may have compilation error, with `multiple definitions for the same symbol`.

Answer (score -1):

Including *.cpp works.

But the real solution is to use the tool make.

Create a makefile, which defines the dependencies, then call make, which then calls the compiler appropriatly.

Comment: `make` just automates build steps that you can run by hand. In and of itself, a Makefile doesn't buy you anything. (Also, there are other build tools.)